# Среда для решения упражнений из K&R?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, среду работы для решения задач(упражнений) из K&R на языке СИ.
Просто, при работе с MS VS 2010 возникает много проблем, он не дружит с чистым СИ походу.
Пример кода который не компилируется в VS 2010.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /*максимальный размер вводимой строки*/

int getline(char line[],int MAXLINE);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/*печать самой длинной строки*/

main()
{
    int len; /*длина текущей страны*/
    int max; /*длина максимальной из просмотренных строк*/

    char line[MAXLINE]; /*ТЕКУЩАЯ СТРОКА*/
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /*самая длинная строка*/

    max = 0;

    while(len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if(len > max)
        {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
        if (max > 0) /*была ли хоть одна строка*/
            printf("%s",longest);
        return 0;
}

/* getline: читает строку в s, возращает длину*/

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c,i;

    for(i=0; i< lim-1 &&(c= getchar()) != EOF && c != "\n"; ++i)
        s[i]=c;
    if(c=="\n")
    {
        s[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy: копирует из "form"  в "to"; to достаточно большой*/
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;

}
```

Код ошибки:

```
    1>------ Построение начато: проект: KandR, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Построение начато 30.03.2012 16:41:07.
1>ClCompile:
1>  1.9.c
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(4): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед "константа"
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(4): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие "{" перед "константа"
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(4): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: <Нет данных>
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(4): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(19): warning C4013: getline: нет определения; предполагается "extern" с возвратом типа "int"
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(19): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед ">"
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(19): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: )
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(25): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: if
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(27): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: return
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(28): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: }
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\kandr\kandr\1.9.c(38): error C2001: newline в константе
1>
1>СБОЙ построения.
1>
1>Затраченное время: 00:00:00.18
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста как именно он не дружит.

Comment: Переписал 1:1 код(позже надоело проверять, тупо скопировал и вставил) из K&R, но VS 2010 выдаёт кучу ошибок. Пример кода сечас встевлю.

Comment: VS вроде вообще не поддерживает Си, только C++.

Comment: Я когда на курсы при Бауманке ходил, там в VS 2008 сишный код нормально компилировался, и домашния задания нормально получаются.
Я вот стал читать K&R, так геморой, ничего не работает и не компилируется, иногда работает своеобразно.

Comment: Часть программ на Си успешно компилируются транслятором C++. Но не все.

Comment: Что бы вот это значило?

         int getline(char line[],int MAXLINE);

Т.е. как это понимать?. Если натравить на ваш филе cpp (это отдельный макропроцессор, то сторка станет

         int getline(char line[],int 1000);

Как транслятору это понимать? (И ещё учтите, что getline определена в stdio.h Для уменьшения проблем рекомендую её переименовать во что-нибудь. (Так что полёп на "Выжрал Студию" отметаем)

Comment: И кто там (@ВладиславМСК, это не Вам) за define'ы-то агитировал? Вот наглядная задница этого инструмента.

Comment: define-ы (при таких издателях литературы) тут ни при чем.

В строке 4  вместо MAXLINE надо maxline

В строке 25 надо добавить открывающую скобку перед len

В строках 36 и 38 заменить символы " на '


Компилятор gcc из MinGW. 

--

Насчет задницы, да для криворуких кроликов, неспособных для лазанья, это полная задница, и ничего для них не изменится, пока они не будут ежедневно серьезно тренироваться и вдумчиво анализировать собственные ошибки.

Comment: Ну в реализациях чего-либо через макропроцессор диагностика ошибок -- традиционно узкое место. (Один из серьёзных недостатков). В 70е-80е годы -- да, было обоснованно, когда компутеры были большими, а их возможности -- маленькими. А вообще, кролик с кривыми руками -- это страшно.

Comment: Так я не понял, кролик это я?

Comment: Подозреваю, что кроликом @avp меня обозвал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задумайтесь об этих строчках

```
#define MAXLINE 1000 /*максимальный размер вводимой строки*/
int getline(char line[],int MAXLINE);
```

Comment: Ребят, глава 1,9 K&R, я просто оттуда переписал.

Comment: Да, в моей (издание Санкт-Петербург 2001 г.) тоже самое. Правда со скобкой и кавычками все ОК. 

--

Могу предположить, что родной (старый) компилятор воспринимал в прототипах **только типы**, имена аргументов просто пропускал, не анализируя. 

Ведь можно же прототип записать и так:

    int getline(char *, int);

Comment: Причем здесь старый компилятор? Если в книжке так, значит в книжке ошибка (случай нередкий. Вот Эккель утверждает, что он свои примеры проверяет, но насчёт других авторов -- кто их знает), потому как тут не имя, а цифры. А вот если переписать -- будет правильно. (И для нового, и для старого).

Comment: Для первого издания ((c) Bell Telephone Laboratories, Incorporated 1978) **возможно** этот пример работал правильно. Того компилятора уже не найти, а @ВладиславМСК возможно первый с тех пор, проверивший этот пример.

Comment: Этого не могло быть.  (Я не помню, был ли в K&R C тип void). Увы, книжки под рукой нету. Посмотрел вики -- void был заимствован из C++

Comment: В книжке С. Баурн "Операционная Система UNIX", оригинал от 1983 г. **void** уже есть.

Ну, и лично я не помню C без void.

Comment: Достали, однако. http://linux.yaroslavl.ru/docs/prog/c/ch01.html#1.8 -- пример этого программа из перевода от 1982г. http://letrongngoc.tech.officelive.com/Documents/TheCProgrammingLanguageSecondEdition.pdf p.30 (отметьте прототип getline, он там написан правильно)

Answer (score 1):

Любая среда которая пользуется компилятором gcc или clang (Любой поддерживающий ANSI C).
Например Code::Blocks или Qt Creator.

Comment: Я так понял, VS 2010 этим скуп?

Comment: Именно. Поддержки Си нет.

Answer (score 0):

Для Windows я использую MinGW, UnixUtils и Emacs. Эта тройка хороша тем, что не требует установки. Скопировал с флэшки, в PATH прописал и делай что надо.

Можно еще поставить MSYS. Это легкая unix-подобная среда в винде.